# How to get async await work in airtable api with node js to get all records in the airtable before sending resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, airtable

I am trying to get my record from airtable using async await. What i want is that once airtable has fetched all the records it should return a value 1 which will be assigned to a variable counter. Once value of counter is 1 it can be used to access other data as well. The problem is that since airtable api has a record limit of 1. Even before it reaches all the elements it sets the value of counter to 1. I know this is weird because page function should be called in airtable api before done function unless it has traversed across all the records. Here is my code :

```
var counter = 0;

async function FirstCall(){
    counter = await backlinksubmissionChecker.getData();
    console.log("Counter value is ",counter);
    if(counter==1){
        counter = await codequalityXP.getData(); 
        console.log("Counter value is ",counter);
    }
}
```

my code for airtable api access  is like this

```
async function getData()
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("Inside Backlink submission checker");
            var i=0;
            let value =  base("Program XP").select({      
            }).eachPage(function page(records, fetchNextPage) {   
                records.forEach(function(record) {
                    let recordID =  record.get("RecordID");
                    let email = record.get("Email Address");
                    ConnectStudents(recordID,email);
                 i++;
                });
                fetchNextPage();
            }, function done(err) {
                if (err) { 
                console.error(err);
                reject("Promise rejected");
                }else{
                resolve(1);
            }
            }); 
      });
}
```

How do I ensure that my airtable api has brought me all the records before it sends a resolve promise which tells that it has traversed through all records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using [Airtable's NodeJS SDK](https://github.com/Airtable/airtable.js).  There's a built in function for selecting all records which I think simplifies your code greatly and decreases the risk of other errors.

```
async function getData() {
  console.log("Inside Backlink submission checker");
  const records = await base('Program XP').select().all();

  var i = 0;
  records.forEach(function(record) {
      let recordID =  record.get("RecordID");
      let email = record.get("Email Address");
      ConnectStudents(recordID,email);
      i++;
  });

  return 1;
}

getData()
  .then((res)=>console.log("DONE: ", res))
  .catch((err)=>{console.log("ERR: ", err)});
```

> The problem is that since airtable api has a record limit of 1

The GET method for Airtable's API returns 1 page at a time with a default of 100 records per page.  If you have less than 100 records in the table you are making the GET request to, then it will return all records in a single call.

If your `ConnectStudents` function is asynchronous, it may not be fully processing each record, but it does look like the Airtable API is returning all of the records to your system.